# What is the difference between a Web application and Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web-applications

It sounds naive on hearing but how different are web application and Web API when someone mentions it in their paper?
How different are they from their functionalities?

Comment: Most web applications returns both views and data but Web API is used to create full blown HTTP services with easy and simple way that returns only data not view.

Answer (score 25):

Very short: web application, it's a web site, which you see in your browser, and web api, it's a service, which you use in a web application.

See also [Difference between ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/webapi/difference-between-aspnet-mvc-and-aspnet-web-api):

> Asp.Net MVC is used to create web applications that returns both views
>   and data but Asp.Net Web API is used to create full blown HTTP
>   services with easy and simple way that returns only data not view.

Comment: How then can i create web site as separate client if i created solution as Asp.Net Web API already?  Does visual studio support a project template as client app (web site or should I say web page)?

Comment: @JP_medevice, no such project template, Web API can be used in different applications, for example: ASP.NET, HTML/JavaScript, mobile app, and even descktop

Answer (score 13):

**Web Application:**

It is an end-to-end solution for a user. Which means, User can:

- Open it using a browser
- Interact with it. He can click on something and after some processing, its result will be reflected in the browser screen. Human-System interaction

**Web API**

With Web APIs alone, a user can not interact with it, because it only returns data, not views.

- It is a system which interacts with another system
- It does not return views, it returns data
- It has an endpoint set, which can be hit by other systems to get data which it provides.

**Explanation using an ANALOGY**

**Web Application:**

Suppose we have a cook. We can ask him to cook us anything, anytime!Suppose we ask our cook to cook us a burger. He'll process our request and will provide us a burger. ( This is like a Web Application; a complete solution. )

**Web API**

Now if we ask him to make us 'McDonalds' burger, can he cook and bring us that? No!
Here comes the concept of APIs! *(for this example, lets suppose McDonalds only give takeaways to cooks only)*

McDonalds-Takeaways is like an API. Which allows other systems (cooks) to hit it and bring back desired data. So we can ask our solution (our cook) to

- go to McDonalds Takeaway
- Buy the burger and bring us that

So what happened is, we asked our "System" to talk to this McDonalds-takeaways (API System) and bring back the result we desired.

Comment: That's awesome analogy and pure clear-cut explanation. Good job bro...

Comment: Very precise explanation!

Answer (score 12):

Web Applications are meant for their human interactions through views whereas Web API aka Web Services are meant for system-to-system interactions (information exchange programatically ). They exchange data.

Answer (score 2):

Web app is a website that is running in your browser and web Api is service

Answer (score 1):

Web API is back-end application(server side) where actual functionality to call service/database call is happening to store and retrieve the data.

Web Application is front end application(client side)which is calling web API to present the data retrieved from back-end.

eg: To check the account balance in your mobile banking app, you are able to see your account details in front end. But all the calculations of interest /balance is happening in the back end.

Answer (score 0):

In simplest word, a web application's response to requests are html, css, javascript and anything that a browser can render (graphical), whereas a web api returns non-graphical "data". Having said that, I think we can make a web api work like a web application because html is still data.

Answer (score -2):

```
Create :

    public IHttpActionResult GetAllProduct()
        {
            IList<product> pro = null;

            using (var ctx = new TestMVCEntities())
            {
                pro = ctx.products.ToList();


            }

            if (pro.Count == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(pro);
        }

        public IHttpActionResult PostNewProduct(product pro)
        {

            using (var ctx = new TestMVCEntities())
            {

                ctx.InUPProduct(pro.pid,pro.pname,pro.pprice);

                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            return Ok();
        }

        public IHttpActionResult PutOldProduct(product pro)
        {

            using (var ctx = new TestMVCEntities())
            {

                product c = (from x in ctx.products
                              where x.pid == pro.pid
                              select x).First();

                if (c != null)
                {
                    c.pname = pro.pname;
                    c.pprice = pro.pprice;
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
            }

            return Ok();
        }

        public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
        {

            using (var ctx = new TestMVCEntities())
            {
                var pro = ctx.products
                    .Where(s => s.pid == id)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                ctx.Entry(pro).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            return Ok();
        }




Consume :

  public JsonResult GetProductsData()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44350/api/");
                //HTTP GET
                var responseTask = client.GetAsync("product");
                responseTask.Wait();

                var result = responseTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<product>>();
                    readTask.Wait();

                    var alldata = readTask.Result;

                    var rsproduct = from x in alldata
                                 select new[]
                                 {
                                 Convert.ToString(x.pid),
                                 Convert.ToString(x.pname),
                                 Convert.ToString(x.pprice),
                                 Convert.ToString(x.pimage),
                                 Convert.ToString(x.pisdemand),
                                 Convert.ToString(x.pcname),
                                 Convert.ToString(x.psupply)

                          };

                    return Json(new
                    {
                        aaData = rsproduct
                    },
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


                }
                else //web api sent error response 
                {

                   var pro = Enumerable.Empty<product>();


                    return Json(new
                    {
                        aaData = pro
                    },
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


                }
            }
        }

        public JsonResult InupProduct(string id,string pname, string pprice)
        {
            try
            {



                product obj = new product
                {
                    pid = Convert.ToInt32(id),
                    pname = pname,
                    pprice = Convert.ToDecimal(pprice)
                };



                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44350/api/product");

                    //HTTP POST
                    var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<product>("product", obj);
                    postTask.Wait();

                    var result = postTask.Result;
                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Json(0, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                }


                /*context.InUPProduct(Convert.ToInt32(id),pname,Convert.ToDecimal(pprice));

                return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);*/
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(0, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }

        public JsonResult deleteRecord(int ID)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44350/api/product");

                    //HTTP DELETE
                    var deleteTask = client.DeleteAsync("product/" + ID);
                    deleteTask.Wait();

                    var result = deleteTask.Result;
                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {

                        return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Json(0, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                }



               /* var data = context.products.Where(x => x.pid == ID).FirstOrDefault();
                context.products.Remove(data);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return Json(1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);*/
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(0, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you submit this to the wrong question?